# Bound action creators typescript component types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a full set of typed action creators in redux, that I am binding to props in a react component. I'm curious if it is standard practice to add types to the component props, even though the action creators they receive are already typed.

```
// Action Creator: Here I am typing the action creator for the first time
export interface FetchingUserSuccessReturn {
  type: string;
  uid: string;
  user: any;
  timestamp: number;
}

export function fetchingUserSuccess(uid: string, user: any, timestamp: number): FetchingUserSuccessReturn {
  return {
    type: FETCHING_USER_SUCCESS,
    uid,
    user,
    timestamp
  };
}
```

Is it typical to leave out the component props interface, since the props are already typed (as action creators)?

```
// Component receiving action creator
// It feels like I'm re-typing the action creators in this interface
interface MainContainerProps {
  fetchingUserSuccess: (uid: string, user: any, timestamp: number) => FetchingUserSuccessReturn;
}


export default connect(
  () => (),
  (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
      fetchingUserSuccess: userActionCreators.fetchingUserSuccess,
    }, dispatch);
  }
)(MainContainer);

export class MainContainer extends React.Component<MainContainerProps, any>     {
...
```